# Where are the plugin settings for Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, version-control, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I added some plugins and am wondering which file(s) the plugins list is stored in. I want to get it into version control. It kind of looks like they're in `plugins/{platform}.json`, but from I've seen that folder is supposed to be exclude from version control. I've also seen reference to a `plugins.xml`, but I don't see that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you saw that that plugins folder should not be under version control but I personally don't see other way of saving plugins than saving the whole plugins folder.

The plugin.xml you mentioned is the file describing each plugin's structure, it's in each subfolder of the plugins folder.

### Edit:

If you really don't want to save plugins in your version control, you can have a look at [this link on how to use hooks to install plugins](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/). The bad side is that doing this you get latest version of plugins and so may experience different behaviour depending on plugins version installed. It may be a good idea to add plugin version.

Comment: Thanks QuickFix! I saw it months ago when I was looking for .gitignore examples for AngularJS. Now that I'm adding some plugins, I'm find that it was wrong.

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could post your .gitignore to see if there is anything I might be missing.